# Adding the ! operator and sqrt(), pow(), etc. to a calculator example application

Tags: c++

I'm doing the exercises in Stroustrup's new book ["Programming Principles and Practice Using C++"](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) and was wondering if anyone on Stack Overflow has done them and is willing to share the knowledge?

Specifically about the calculator that's developed in Chap 6 and 7. For example, the questions about adding the `!` operator and sqrt(), pow(), etc. I have done these, but I don't know if the solution I have is the "good" way of doing things, and there are no published solutions on Bjarne's website. I'd like to know if I am going down the right track. Maybe we can make a wiki for the exercises?

Basically I have a token parser. It reads a char at a time from cin. It's meant to tokenise expressions like 5*3+1 and it works great for that. One of the exercises is to add a sqrt() function. So I modified the tokenising code to detect "sqrt(" and then return a Token object representing sqrt. In this case I use the char 's'. Is this how others would do it? What if I need to implement sin()? The case statement would get messy.

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;    // Note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

switch (ch) {
    case ';':    // For "print"
    case 'q':    // For "quit"
    case '(':
    case ')':
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '!':
        return Token(ch);        // Let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        {
            cin.putback(ch);         // Put digit back into the input stream
            double val;
            cin >> val;              // Read a floating-point number
            return Token('8', val);   // Let '8' represent "a number"
        }
    case 's':
        {
            char q, r, t, br;
            cin >> q >> r >> t >> br;
            if (q == 'q' && r == 'r' && t == 't' && br == '(') {
                cin.putback('(');    // Put back the bracket
                return Token('s');   // Let 's' represent sqrt
            }
        }

    default:
        error("Bad token");
}
```

Comment: Just post your code here, and plenty of people will be happy to tell you what can be improved. This site is all the wiki you need. :)

Comment: Haven't seen the exercise, but what seems strange is that you try to make double out of every digit and decimal point that you encounter.

Comment: If the input reads 'sin(2)', then your code will read the 'i', 'n', and '(' into q, r, t; it then decides that these are not collectively 'q', 'r', and 't', so ... it abandons everything.  You need to look at the error recovery rather harder, I believe.

Comment: @Zilupe - it works because we want to treat all numbers as a double. We pushback the char or decimal point as we scan it, then read in the value as a double. Because the input string might be 3*5.34+1. In the case of 5.34 we read the first char ('5') then put it back into cin, then read 5.34 as a double with the next cin.

Comment: I do believe Bjarne Stroustrup himself has answered your question.

Comment: @MichaelMyers: I don't think he answered the question at all.

Comment: OP here. 10 years later I am trying to get back into C++, using Bjarne's 2nd Edition of PPP. I don't know if Bjarne changed the code in Chapters 6 and 7 since the 1st Ed but I found it much easier this time round. 10 years wiser I guess :-)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

1. There are a few solutions posted on [Stroustrup - Programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) and more will be coming over time.
2. Try solving exercises only with the language features and the library facilities presented so far in the book -- real novice users can't do anything else. Then return later to see how a solution can be improved.

Comment: Yes I was kind of cheating with the map...it doesn't appear till later chapters. I am really enjoying the book by the way. I think the calculator might actually be useful in the real world, which is not something you can say about the samples presented in most introductory books.

Comment: are you real one? :P

Comment: @Swift: Probably not. Too many simple grammatical errors and other errors (I don't think the real Bjarne would be that careless). In any case, there hasn't been any activity in the last 10 years on this unregistered account, and the login cookie has probably been lost.

Comment: Wait, user *iammilind* introduced grammatical errors (or rather, changed the meaning).

Answer (score 10):

I thought a map of strings to function pointers might be a concise way to represent things like sqrt, sin, cos, etc. that take a single double and return a double:

```
map<std::string, double (*)(double)> funcs;
funcs["sqrt"] = &sqrt;
funcs["sin"] = &sin;
funcs["cos"] = &cos;
```

Then when the parser detects a correct string (str) it can call the function with an argument (`arg`) like so:

```
double result = funcs[str](arg);
```

With this method, a single call can handle all cases of functions (of that type).

Actually I'm not sure if that's the correct syntax, can anyone confirm?

Does this seem like a usable method?

Comment: It might, but Bjarne Stroustrup answered your question. Bow down.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to work with derived classes and virtual functions: each specialized class reading its own input...

```
class base {
    public:
        virtual double calc() = 0;
};

class get_sqrt : public base {
    int useless;

    public:
        virtual double calc() {
            cin >> number;
            return sqrt(number);
        }
}

get_sqrt;
```

Now we organize these in a map, and we will only use their pointers:

```
map<string,base*> func;
func["sqrt"] = &get_sqrt;
```

There is also a specialized method which only looks at the next character: peek();

```
char c = cin.peek();
```

You can get rid of the switch by using 1 if putting `!`, `+`, `-`, etc. in `func`; (they should operate on left_param for simplicity):

```
 if (c>='0' && c<='9')
     cin >> right_param; // Get a number, you don't have to put the
                         // character back as it hasn't been removed
 else {
     string s;
     cin >> s;
     right_param = func[s]->calc();
 }
```

So basically some kind of function pointers, but without the messy syntax and in which you could store data between calculations.

I thought about the whitespace problem; it can be added before it starts to compute, I also think there could be a way to set different separators, like numbers, but I don't know how.

Comment: Nice. I knew there would be an OOP solution in there somewhere! But...the cin>>s wouldn't work because the expression could contain no whitespace i.e. 5+sqrt(144)/2. So still need to read a char at a time to check function name like sqrt, I think.

Comment: I think it should be peek, not peak! I wonder why Stroustrup didn't use this method, it seems more logical than get() and putback().

Comment: I refrained from using peek() to avoid introducing yet another new facility this early and (more importantly) because "stream with putback()" is a very general idea that can be used in many places - peek() involves someone else doing some buffering for you. Also, think of whitespace and error handling - what if there isn't a next character to peek at? I see peek() more as a "clever trick" than as a general technique.

Comment: Good point. That makes sense. BTW thanks for taking time to check out this thread, I feel privileged to have the author himself providing input!

Answer (score 0):

I would move the 'sqrt' detection into another method for function detection. Essentially, I would remove the 's' detection and add something inside the default case that would read the string up to a '('.

If no '(' is detected, then error.

If you successfully read a string, pass that to a function name parser that uses string compares to generate a token that represents a call to sqrt or sin or whatever function you like. The method that checks for the function names can also error if it reads a string that it doesn't recognize.

Comment: Ok I'll try and implement this. That would separate out the function stuff nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I've finished this task right now, so here's how I did it. (Most of code below is written originally by Stroustrup, there's only my vision of effective sqrt() calculating)

First, it's required to assign a symbolic constant, that'll indicate there's a sqrt() call.
`const char root = 's';`

Now let's make some changes to your code:

```
switch (ch) {
// here were your case: blocks of code
default:
        if (isalpha(ch)) { 
            string s;
            s += ch;
            while (cin.get(ch) && (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch) || ch == '_')) s += ch;
            cin.putback(ch);

            if (s == "sqrt") return Token(root); // sqrt() define
            return Token(var_name, s); 
        }
        error("Bad token");
    }
}
```

In general, this block of code is responsible for defining variables, but we created the `sqrt` "keyword" by entering a sequence of characters `s`,`q`,`r`,`t`.
If there's that keyword, we return a token that represents a `sqrt`.

Now, we just need to make some changes in our grammar, in `primary()` function.

```
double primary() 
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case root:
    case '(':
    {   
    double d = expression();
    if (t.kind == root) {
        if (d < 0) error("sqrt(): non-positive argument");
        return sqrt(d); // calculate square root otherwise
    }
    t = ts.get();
    if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected"); 
    return d;
    }
    // further case blocks
}
```

As you can see, if `root` keychar is encountered, we need to define a `d` variable as a function `expression()` value. While calculating, `expression()` will encounter `(` character and it'll be possible to enter any sequences as an argument of  user's `sqrt()` function and  get a reasonable answer.

Some examples:

```
> let a = 5;
= 5
> sqrt(100);
= 10
> sqrt(a+20-a/2);
= 4.74342
> 1+2/3+sqrt(9);
= 4.66667
> sqrt(a/0);
divide by zero
> sqrt(-1);
sqrt(): non-positive argument
```